# How does this slide switch work?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, switches, mechanical

I want to use this slide switch SL13-213C (DP3T) ([Datasheet](https://www.tme.eu/Document/bbd6392b3682f4758c0bd42aa089661e/sl13213c.pdf)), but I'm not sure about how the connector work.

The first image on the left comes from the datasheet. The rest is my understanding. Is it correct?

[image: slide switch SL13-213C]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. It's a common configuration for slide switches, as opposed to rotary switches, which would have a "common" terminal.